# How to fetch the records failed during JDBC Batch Processing

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am executing the set of SQL statements through JDBC Batch Processing.
How to fetch the records failed during the batch processing.

I am able to get the Record success and failure counts. But not able to fetch the failed records.

```
Statement statement = null;
try {
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    for (String insertQuery : insertQuerys) {
            statement.addBatch(insertQuery);
    }
    statement.executeBatch();
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.info("Error : " + e);
} finally {
    try {
        statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        logger.info("Error : " + e1);
    }
}
```

I expect the records that are failed during the JDBC Batch processing.

Comment: What do you mean by `the failed record`? When a sql statement/query fails, it only returns an error, no `records`. You can only the the sql statement/query itself, which failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch [BatchUpdateException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/BatchUpdateException.html) which has method `int[] getUpdateCounts()` that returns an array of number of rows affected **by each batched statement** in the **order they were added to the batch**.

But an important thing here is that if your single batched statement updates more than one row, you can not tell exactly which rows were affected by the statement and if they even exist in a table (in case of insert or merge statements).

Comment: Be aware that drivers can either stop at the first failure, or continue execution. Depending on this failure handling, update counts either contains the update counts of the successfully executed statements up to the failed statement, or it contains update counts for all statements in the batch with value `Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED` for the statements that failed. And depending on the transaction mode and driver behaviour (auto-commit, transaction abort, etc), any failure might revert everything, including successfully executed statements).